# Google Calendar API v.3 - 'Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, api, google-calendar-api

I have a Web site in Visual Studio 2012 (.NET Framework is 4.0) to which I want to add Google Calendar features. When I follow the instructions to install Calendar API v3 on [Google's site](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/), everything seems to install fine from nuGet. But when I try importing the libraries in my code, I get the infamous "doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found"...

I tested the same approach with a desktop project and it works great. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this error is thrown when the name space or type specified in the library dosen't contain any public member. Make sure the class inside the namespace is public. Hope this works.